# Fast Reports is generating huge PDF files – what can be done?

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, fastreport, rave-reports

When I generate a simple 10-page report with Fast reports 4.12.2 and save it as a PDF it is about 5 Meg’s in size.

A similar report generated in Rave Reports and converted to PDF with eDocEngine is about 50k in size.

This is how the Fast report TfrxPDFExport component is setup:

```
  object frxPDFExport1: TfrxPDFExport
    UseFileCache = True
    ShowProgress = True
    OverwritePrompt = False
    CreationTime = 40993.786098020840000000
    DataOnly = False
    OnBeginExport = frxPDFExport1BeginExport
    PrintOptimized = True
    Outline = False
    Background = False
    HTMLTags = True
    Author = 'FastReport'
    Subject = 'FastReport PDF export'
    ProtectionFlags = [ePrint]
    HideToolbar = False
    HideMenubar = False
    HideWindowUI = False
    FitWindow = False
    CenterWindow = False
    PrintScaling = False
    Left = 216
    Top = 56
  end
```

**What can I do to get the Fast Report generated PDF smaller ?**

Answer (score 7):

This is not an uncommon problem:

- [Fonts embedding in FastReport PDF](www.fast - report.com/en/blog/27/show/)
- https://forums.embarcadero.com/message.jspa?messageID=551654

Your best bet is either

1) Choose a different report generator

2) Don't use FastReport's built-in PDF generator.

For example, you might try [Synopse](http://synopse.info/forum/viewtopic.php?id=781)

Comment: PS: for some reason, SO won't let me enter "www.fast - report.com"

Answer (score 0):

The main properties that will affect size are:

```
  frxPDFExport1.Compressed := true;
  frxPDFExport1.PrintOptimized := false;
  frxPDFExport1.EmbeddedFonts := false;
```

Also consider varying

```
 frxPDFExport1.PictureDPI := 150;
 frxPDFExport1.Quality := 95;
```

Comment: frxPDFExport1.htmltags := false  will reduce size of a report with many pages and many memos drasticaly, aditionaly frxPDFExport1.transparency := false will reduce size too. from 10MB report changing these to false resulten in 1.5MB file size.